# Does heroku support rails 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've just inherited the code for a rails 1 application,
and the owner wants it deployed. Heroku is my go to hosting provider, so wondering if rails 1 can run on Heroku?

Comment: Not if the app requires ruby-1.8. What version of ruby is it running?

Comment: I have a static dump of the source code, by gripping I found there are mentions of ruby-1.8

Comment: Rails 1 is something you'll have to run in a custom VM with an ancient version of Ruby, like 1.8.7. Heroku has no support for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `git push heroku master` to heroku, since there's no Gemfile in rails 1, heroku will fail to recognize your application as a ruby application. You can make up a Gemfile with your vi editor, but I ran in to problems further down the line and ended up actually pasting controllers / models / views on to a freshly made rails 5 application.

So in short 'No'